# Why do i get an error when the sprite hits the corner

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
from turtle import *
import turtle
import time
import random
```

this part down here is the moving for the sprite.

```
def up():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.forward(3)


def right():
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.forward(3)


def left():
    turtle.setheading(180)
    turtle.forward(3)


def down():
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(3)



def pickup():
    turtleXPos = int(turtle.pos()[0])
    teki1XPos = int(teki1.pos()[0])
    # if teki1YPos == turtleYPos and teki1XPos == turtleXPos:
    turtleYPos = int(turtle.pos()[1])
    teki1YPos = int(teki1.pos()[1])

    if int(turtle.distance(teki1)) < 26:
        teki1.color("purple")
        font = ("Courier", 30, "normal")
        teki1.write(coolcubecounter, font=font)
        teki1.hideturtle()
        teki1.goto(random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,100))
        teki1.showturtle()






turtle.listen()
turtle.clone()










#print(type((turtle.turtles().pop())))

#print(turtle.turtles())

#print(turtle.turtles().__getitem__(1))

wnd = turtle.Screen()

wnd.bgcolor("black")
#s=turtle.getscreen()



wnd.setup(666,666)
turtle.addshape("player.gif")
print(type(turtle))
teki=turtle.Turtle
#teki.circle(20)
turtle1=turtle.Turtle()
#turtle1=teki.clone(self= teki)


turtle.shape("player.gif")
#turtle.shape(circle())
penup()



turtle.getshapes()
#wteki.shape("player.gif")



turtle.onkeypress(up,"w")
turtle.onkeypress(right,"d")
turtle.onkeypress(left,"a")
turtle.onkeypress(down,"s")
turtle.onkey(pickup,"e")

teki1 =turtle.Turtle()




teki1.penup()
turtle.addshape("coolcube.gif")
teki1.shape("coolcube.gif")

teki1.goto(0,100)


cubeXandY=teki1.position()

playerXandY=turtle.position()

coolcubecounter=0
#print(cubeXandY==playerXandY)







#loop
#while True:
    #for i in range(10):
        #teki1.setpos(300, 0)
        #pencolor("blue")
        #up()
        #right()
    #for i in range(10):
        #teki1.setpos(300, 300)
        #pencolor("red")
        #left()
        #down()

exitonclick()
```

Comment: It's way easier to help you if you show the error you get :) add that and you are more likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too messy for me to attempt to debug.  Below is a rework of your code.  See if this does what you want and clears up your bug(s):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

FONT = ('Courier', 30, 'normal')

def up():
    player.setheading(90)
    player.forward(3)

def right():
    player.setheading(0)
    player.forward(3)

def left():
    player.setheading(180)
    player.forward(3)

def down():
    player.setheading(270)
    player.forward(3)

coolcubecounter = 0

def pickup():
    global coolcubecounter

    if player.distance(teki) < 26:
        coolcubecounter += 1
        teki.write(coolcubecounter, align='center', font=FONT)

        teki.hideturtle()
        teki.goto(randint(-300, 300), randint(-300, 300))
        teki.showturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(666, 666)

# screen.addshape("player.gif")
# screen.addshape("coolcube.gif")

player = Turtle(shape='turtle')
# player.shape("player.gif")
player.color('red')
player.penup()

teki = Turtle(shape='turtle')
# teki.shape("coolcube.gif")
teki.color('purple')
teki.penup()
teki.sety(100)

screen.onkeypress(up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(right, 'd')
screen.onkeypress(left, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(down, 's')
screen.onkey(pickup, 'e')
screen.listen()
screen.exitonclick()
```